# Corine Land Cover data is not the same as in reality

Tags: qgis, land-cover

I downloaded a CLC2000 shapefile and clipped it after a county shapefile in QGIS. 
The goal was to calculate the total land area, but the amount obtained of 983.759 Ha does not coincide with the real area of the county of 446.600 Ha.
I can not figure out the error,if it's from map CRS or from other sources.

Comment: What CRS is the shapefile using? What CRS is the map/display/view using?

Comment: Try reprojecting your layer into a local CRS, and using the `area($geometry)` function instead of the `$area` function.